# Sending a large string to multiple users

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, file-sharing

My problem is how can I program an android app that sends a large string of alphanumeric characters to multiple android users.

QR code is limited and can't use special characters and lowercase ones.

Is it possible to send the string to multiple android users with the same app?
Just like ShareIt.

Please provide a reference where I can study more.
I'm new to Android, zero knowledge

Comment: `Please provide a reference where I can study more.
I'm new to Android, zero knowledge` Then [you've come to the wrong place, baby](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEaYaNjfFJY), This is **not** a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

One solution approach could be using a server and push messaging service. It can work as follows:

1. When someone (sender) wants to send a message, A query will be sent to the server with the message data.
2. The server receives the message and saves in a database. Here, we will get a reference to the message in database.
3. The server then sends the message to all receivers via push messaging service.
   *Caveat*: The push messaging services have limits on how much data can be sent at a time. This can be overcome by sending the receivers only a reference to the message. In this case -
4. The receiver will query the server with the reference of message.
5. The server will response to the query with the message data.

All of this can be set up using Google's firebase platform. In that - [firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) will provide database, [firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) will handle the request, response logic and also send messages via the [firebase cloud messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages)